# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\aguem\validar.php:6

Tags: php, mysql

Al ingresar tratar de entrar al sistema web que tengo me muestra este error.
para ingresar al sistema a traves del login, trabaja de manera de validacion de usuarios.

se que la nueva version de php admite otro tipo de conexion, sucede que este codigo se realizo en la version anterior de php, motivo por el cual manda este error.

cuento con dos archivos uno conexion.php y otro validar.php

aqui ajunto el los codigos:

**conexion.php**

```html
<?php
         $cons_usuario="root";
         $cons_contra="password";
         $cons_base_datos="name_bd";
         $cons_equipo="localhost";

         $con = mysqli_connect($cons_equipo,$cons_usuario,$cons_contra,$cons_base_datos);   
      ?>
```

**validar.php**

```html
<?php
include("conexion.php");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');

$str="SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE usu_usuario='".$_POST["user"]."' AND usu_clave ='".$_POST["pass"]."'";
$result=mysql_query($str, $con);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$fechact=date("d-m-Y h:i:s a");


if($num_rows>0)
{
    
     while($obj = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     
        if($obj["usu_estado"]==1)
        {
            echo "ok";
            session_start();
            
            if($obj["usu_cargo"]==0){$cargos="Administrador";}else if($obj["usu_cargo"]==1){$cargos="Trabajador";}
            
            $_SESSION['nombre']=$obj["usu_nombre"]." ".$obj["usu_apellido"];
            $_SESSION['cargo']=$cargos;
            $_SESSION['id']=$obj["usu_id"];
            
            
            $str2="INSERT INTO logacceso (la_tipo, la_usu, la_fecha) VALUES (1,".$obj["usu_id"].", '".$fechact."')";
            mysql_query($str2, $con);
            
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Usuario desactivado del sistema.";
            $str2="INSERT INTO logacceso (la_tipo, la_usu, la_fecha) VALUES (3,".$obj["usu_id"].", '".$fechact."')";
            mysql_query($str2, $con);
        }
     
     }
    
}
else
{
    echo "Error de validacion";
    
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar

Comment: La version PHP Version 7.4.11

Comment: ahi el origen del fallo, en PHP 7.* todas las funciones de mysql_* han sido removidas, motivo por el cual deberás a parte de mirar el enlace que te paso mudar tu código a mysqli o PDO